# Strange PackageTmp when create deploy package with msdeploy in asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, msdeploy

I have the following path to my asp.net (with mvc) project:

```
D:\testAppMvc\testAppMvc.sln
```

I have installed `msdeploy` from [here](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) (no settings were made).

In Visual Studio 2010, right click on project-> `Build Deployment package`. Until now is ok.

If I open the ZIP package I see the strange path to my project necessary files for IIS.

`\Content\D_C\testAppMvc\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\`

Are there any way to change that path for deploy source files or it is unchangeable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set this in your project file:

```xml
<!-- Must be after Microsoft.WebApplication.targets import -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <_PackageTempDir>C:\Package</_PackageTempDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that "right click on project->`Build Deployment package`" in Visual Studio 2010 has become "right click on project->`Publish...`" in Visual Studio 2013.

[How to: Deploy a Web Application Project Using a Web Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN provides details on publishing a deployment package in VS 2013.

To publish a deployment package in VS 2013, I created a custom publish profile named Local Package, then chose the *Web Deploy Package* publish method - screenshots below:

[image: VS 2013 Web Publish - Profile]

[image: VS 2013 Web Publish - Connection]