# Publishing project with files with very long names

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish a project in Visual Studio 2013 that has some files with very long names, including the path location. I moved the project to a location closer to my root C:\ drive, which allows it to compile, but when publishing, it tries to copy files to the %appdata% folder which results in a name over the limit.

Here is the error I get:

```
Error   10  Copying file node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\bower-config\node_modules\optimist\node_modules\minimist\.travis.yml to C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\WebProject--1320288221\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\bower-config\node_modules\optimist\node_modules\minimist\.travis.yml failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.     0   0   WebProject
```

Is there a way to either adjust this project's name or where it copies to temporarily so that I am able to publish from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Citing [@Britton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682081/britton) from [Temp path too long when publishing a web site project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526022/temp-path-too-long-when-publishing-a-web-site-project):

> Add this to your publish profile to modify the temporary directory for
>   package/publish:

```
<AspnetCompileMergeIntermediateOutputPath>c:\shortPath\</AspnetCompileMergeIntermediateOutputPath>
```

Or according to [Website publish failing due to file path being too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411136/website-publish-failing-due-to-file-path-being-too-long) (citing [@Jason Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121493/jason-beck) and [@VeeKayBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438624/veekaybee)):

> Add the following line in default PropertyGroup of web project file:

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>..\Temp</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

Comment: I used the second solution (`<IntermediateOutputPath>..\Temp</IntermediateOutputPath>`) and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. BTW, it would be great if you can also credit the people cited in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Amnon Shochot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29421906/4427457), above, I also had to apply [Roland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12269469/4427457) from another thread.

My publish paths (in .pubxml) now look like this:

```
<publishUrl>c:\publish\proj\</publishUrl>
<IntermediateOutputPath>c:\publish\inter\</IntermediateOutputPath>
<_PackageTempDir>c:\publish\package</_PackageTempDir>
```

You have to be careful with this:

[image: Delete all existing files]

**Important:**  If this option is set, be sure not to nest your temporary files inside the *publishUrl* directory, because it will wipe out the *_PackageTempDir* files, causing a failed publish, even if it appears successful.